# Accessing custom exception code when calling NUnit assert method

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

I have an unit test method like below.

```
    [TestCase("test")]
    [TestCase("")]
    public void ParseResponse_InvalidResponse_ReturnsBusException(string responseMessage)
    {
        IResponseParser responseParser = new ResponseParser();           

        Assert.That(() => responseParser.parseHtmlResponse(responseMessage), 
              Throws.Exception.TypeOf<WebApiBusinessException>());

    }
```

My WebApiBusinessException class has a custom errorCode. I would like to add another assert and read thrown business exception's error code to make sure that it was expected one. I can do this by adding try / catch block. Is it possible to do this with no try / catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it

```
[TestCase("test")]
[TestCase("")]
public void ParseResponse_InvalidResponse_ReturnsBusException(string responseMessage)
{
    IResponseParser responseParser = new ResponseParser();           

    Assert.That(() => responseParser.parseHtmlResponse(responseMessage), 
          Throws.Exception.TypeOf<WebApiBusinessException>()
              .And.Property("ErrorCode").EqualTo("3"));

}
```

Comment: I didn't know this was an option!

Comment: I was about to add try / catch for this :) @JamesFaix

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `Assert.Throws<T>(Action)`;